# I can't use onlyTrashed method on datapanel in laravel

Tags: laravel, datatable, soft-delete

I have a problem with Laravel datatable SoftDelete method in Laravel. I use onlyTrashed() function to get the data but all data is coming.I am using the latest version yajrabox.

Frist try:

```
public function trash(Request $request){
    $datalists = DataTables::of(Datapanel::onlyTrashed())->onlyTrashed()->make(true);
    return view('back.cancelpanel');
}
```

Second try:

```
public function trash(Request $request){
if ($request->ajax()) {
        return Datatables::of(Datapanel::onlyTrashed())
            ->onlyTrashed()
            ->make(true);
    }

    return view('back.cancelpanel');
}
```

Third try:(In this try i reached the data deleted with json data but I didn't know how to direct it to datatable.)

```
public function trash(Request $request){
    $datalists = DataTables::of(Datapanel::onlyTrashed())->make(true);
    return response()->json($datalists);
}
```

Comment: Does it work with `DataTables::of(Datapanel::onlyTrashed()->get())->make(true)`? `onlyTrashed()` doesn't return a Collection, it's still a Builder instance at that point. `->get()` converts to a Collection, so it _should_ work, but I haven't used `DataTables` in a while...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved the problem. The problem was that i used the same ajax url: route in different blade.php.But your code is also working correctly.

Comment: @TimLewis FYI `DataTables::of()` can take a `Collection` (Eloquent or not), `Builder`, or `ApiResource` object; it all gets sorted out in the back end into the appropriate builder class.

Comment: @miken32 Ok cool; I wasn't sure if it was relying on a specific type of Object or if it would extrapolate and add a closure as required. Thanks for clarifying :)